# bash: how to make a clickable link with query parameters?

Tags: bash, url, search

I am trying to dump url on the terminal that needs to be clickable, and the url comes with a query parameter. For example --

```
google='https://www.google.com/search?q='
orgname='foo bar'
gsearch=$google\'$orgname\' 
echo "details: $orgname ($gsearch)"
```

But the problem is that the clickable link totally omits everything after the `q=`, i.e. does not include the string `'foo bar'`, please see the image below --

[image]

How do I make a clickable link that includes the query (i.e. the whole url in the braces above)?

*Please also note that I am adding quote in the search parameter since the it may contain spaces.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quotes are not valid in URLs. Use the URL encoding `%27` instead:

```
google='https://www.google.com/search?q='
orgname='foo'
gsearch=$google%27$orgname%27
echo "details: $orgname ($gsearch)"
```

Note that it's the terminal and not your script that decides what's considered part of a URL for the purpose of selecting or clicking. The above results in

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%27foo%27
```

which is more clickable in most terminals. The script can't specify what's the extent of the URL except through expressing it in such a standard way that each individual terminal emulator has a decent chance of recognizing it.

PS: I don't think Google cares about surrounding single quotes.

Comment: hi thanks, but the problem is that the search string may contain spaces which I forgot to mention in the question. Now the problem is that if I add `%27`, the link omits everything after the space, i.e. if there is `%27foo bar%27`, then the terminal link catches everything upto `%27foo` then stops. Any idea? Please review the question as it has been updated.

Comment: @ramgorur forget the single quotes or `%27` altogether - it is the space you want to replace with `%20`